# Magento template istallation error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, theme

always If I want to install a themplate, I get an error.
Can you help me pleas?
Error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:215:"Error in file: "/usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Blog/sql/cmsmart_blog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'cmsmart_blog' already exists";i:1;s:936:"
#0 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.0.0', '1.0.5')
#2 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.0.0', '1.0.5')
#3 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /usr/www/users/mstqsq/index.php(87): Mage::run('default')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your database `cmsmart_blog` table. Is it empty? If yes do not hesitate to delete it and run installation again.

To prevent such situations module vendors usually add `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` construction.

Probably you can try to fix the setup file which cause an issue with this construction. How to do that - you can look it in any magento core module.

Comment: where can I find cmsmart_blog table ?

Comment: ok i had looked inapp/code/local/ there is no folder named cmsmarkt

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem!
I just had to clear the cache completly, I just saw all active in my backend but as I looked in my fdp cache there weher something.